# Create new USB Endpoint in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, libusb, intel-edison

I have an Intel Edison that I would like to use as a USB device capable of responding to queries made by a host. Currently, it is serving as a USB device providing functionality such as a serial com port, and a filesystem (as well as providing power). I need a way to add an additional endpoint to this USB interface so that I can bind my own custom application to it and make it accessible by the host. Alternatively, I could create another virtual com port to communicate with the host over serial.

However, I have scoured the internet, and poured over libusb, and still have no idea as to how I would do this. For reference, the Edison runs a flavor of Linux called "Yocto."

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand, you need to communicate with another device via USB, programming communication with libusb?

Comment: I want my host machine to be able to send data to this device over usb and receive a response. Presumably I would program at least the device's end with libusb, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: And the programming language has to be C?

Comment: No, I just figured that would be the most likely solution

Comment: Try to PyUSB python LIbrary or hidapi for C , libusb is more complex :)

Comment: Do you speack spanish ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. However, while these libraries look nice, they only seem to communicate with a usb endpoint that already exists. I see no way to create a new endpoint. Am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84218/discussion-between-santiago92-and-zwade).